# Django Test Client POST not sending data

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, unit-testing, django-views

I'm using Django 1.11, Python 3.6 and Visual Studio and I'm trying to run my unit tests but I have some problems testing view methods for processing forms.

That's my test:

```
def test_post_newComment(self):
    # Login
    self.client.login(username="user1", password="user1")

    # Data form
    data = {'title': 'Test', 'queja':2}

    # Response to post client request
    response = self.client.post(reverse('newComment'), data)

    # Check response
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
    ....
```

And here's my Views.py method where debugging I can see that request.POST is a empty dict so the form is never filled in the self.client.post.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def nuevoComentario(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)

    # User validation
    if not (request.user.is_authenticated):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

    # If the forms has been submitted
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
            ...
```

The request.POST is always an empty dict. I have tried to add "content_type" parameter to the self.client.post request but I also obtain the same result (request.POST reachs empty to the views.py method).

Comment: hi @ÁlvaroSL . Did you solve this issue? I think I have same right now...

Answer (score -3):

It looks like what you are missing is that `data=data` in your `client.post`